# custom service for http not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have defined a custom service for making $http requests like this:

```
app.factory("ajaxCall",["$http",'$q',function($http,$q){    
return {
        getData : function(url){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(url).then(function(data)
            {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
        return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

And I am using this service in my resolve like:

```
    resolve:{

                tableData: function(ajaxCall){
                 return {
                  ajaxCall.getData({/* A Url */}); //line a
                 } 

                } 
            }
```

But its giving me an error: Unexpected identifier at line a.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get(url)` expects `url` to be  string but you are trying to wrap that string in `{}`

Also the `resolve` syntax is incorrect.

Try

```
resolve: {
   tableData: function(ajaxCall) {
     return ajaxCall.getData( /* A Url */ ); 
   }
 }
```

Also you are using a promise  anti pattern in factory which can be simplified to:

```
app.factory("ajaxCall", ["$http", '$q',
  function($http, $q) {
    return {
      getData: function(url) {
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });    
      };
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write valid javascript (you've got way tooo much curly braces over there):

```
resolve: {
    tableData: function(ajaxCall) {
        return ajaxCall.getData('http://....');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use app.factory or app.service. As example :

```
app.factory('service', ['$http', function ($http) {       

    return {
        save: function (data) {
            return $http({
                url: 'your url is here',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data
            })
        },
     };
}]);
```

And then in angular-controller:

```
 $scope.addButtonClick = function () {

            var info = {};
            info ["Id"] = $scope.Id;                
            info ["name"] = $scope.name;
            info ["pwd"] = $scope.pwd;

            service.save(info )
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.reset();
            })
            .error(function (xhr) {
                $ngBootbox.alert('Error in saving data');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice